# NGINX not responding

Tags: nginx, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have three sites configured on my server using NGINX and the first two are working fine.  One is a static site and one is running Rails (using Unicorn).  I have attempted to mirror the NGINX/Unicorn configurations.

For the non-working site, I get "problem loading site" in my browser and absolutely nothing in my NGINX error logs (even at debug level) or my Unicorn log.  I also get nothing when I attempt to cURL to the site.

I have double checked DNS by pinging domain name and am running out of ideas.  I've also tried making this the default server and browsing by IP address.

Thoughts on how I should go about debugging?  I would like to at least understand if NGINX is seeing these requests or not.

NGINX configuration:

```
upstream unicorn-signup {
  server unix:/home/signup/app/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/signup/app/current/public;
        server_name signup.quote2bill.com;

        # configure for Unicorn (NGINX acts as reverse proxy)
        location / {
                try_files $uri @unicorn;
        }

        location @unicorn {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://unicorn-signup;
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                proxy_send_timeout 300s;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are your OS RedHat based ? In this case, maybe your Firewall (iptables) are denying traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Survivor.  I am running `Ubuntu` and `ufw` for firewall.  I've tried disabling the firewall as well.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed!  It was the dreaded `force_ssl` flag in my production configuration.  For future travelers, here is how I went about troubleshooting:

1. Went on a Costco run to clear my mind and buy huge quantities of stuff.
2. To determine if it was a DNS, NGINX or Unicorn/Rails problem, I replaced my NGINX configuration with a very simple one and placed a simple `index.html` in my public root.  This worked fine - which lets DNS off the hook (I could resolve the domain name at the web server).
3. I diff'd the working and non-working NGINX configuration files for the nth time and made them as close as possible but didn't find anything.
4. Then I noticed that when I was serving the simple `index.html` file in #2 above, the domain was not getting redirected to `https://` but when switched to my "normal" Unicorn/Rails version, I was always getting redirected.
5. I searched for Rails redirecting to SSL and remembered the `force_ssl` flag.
6. I checked my two projects and noticed the flag was not set in the working project, but set in the non-working one (smoking gun).
7. I changed, committed, redeployed and reloaded the browser and it... didn't work (!)  Fortunately, I had the good sense to [clear browser cache](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) and try again and it is all good now.

Hope this helps someone.